# output problems with proc_open()

Tags: php, proc-open

I have a small PHP-written CLI script which works as a front-end to CLI-based `calc` from Linux. The script gets mathematical expressions from user and passes them to `calc`. Then when user wants to quit he simply enters `stop`. In this case the script sends `exit` to `calc`. The problem with this script is that it displays output only in the end when user sends `stop`. But I need to have the output of each user's mathematical expression. The script is below:

```
 <?php

    define('BUFSIZ', 1024);
    define('EXIT_CMD', 'stop');

    function printOutput(&$fd) {
         while (!feof($fd)) {
            echo fgets($fd, BUFSIZ);
        }   
    }

    function &getDescriptorSpec()
    {
        $spec = array(
            0 => array("pty"), // stdin
            1 => array("pty"), // stdout
            2 => array("pty") // stderr
        );
        return $spec;
    }

    function readInputLine(&$fd)
    {
        echo "Enter your input\n";
        $line = trim(fgets($fd)); 
        return $line;
    }

    function sendCmd(&$fd, $cmd)
    {
        fwrite($fd, "${cmd}\n");
    }

    function main() {

        $spec = getDescriptorSpec();
        $process = proc_open("calc", $spec, $pipes);
        if (is_resource($process)) {
            $procstdin = &$pipes[0];
            $procstdout = &$pipes[1];
            $fp = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
            while (TRUE) {
                $line = readInputLine($fp);
                if (0 === strcmp($line, EXIT_CMD)) {
                    break;
                }
                sendCmd($procstdin, $line);

            }    
            sendCmd($procstdin, "exit");
            fclose($procstdin);
            printOutput($procstdout);
            fclose($procstdout);
            $retval = proc_close($process);
            echo "retval = $retval\n";
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

    main();
```

Comment: Try using `flush()` as the output is most likely being buffered.

Comment: Yes, `flush()` + some code modification did it! Do you know where can I post modified code which now works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the CLI version of PHP, the output is still buffered - so the usual time that a page is sent to the user is at the end of the script.

As with any version of PHP - using `flush()` will force the output to be sent to the user.

Also - you should use `PHP_EOL`, it outputs the correct new lines for whatever platform your on (linux and Windows use different chars - \r\n or \n).  `PHP_EOL` is a safe way of creating a new line.